# AttributeError: module 'plotly.offline' has no attribute 'PLOTLY OFFLINE INITIALIZED'

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

I am trying to plot data using following code :-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
import cufflinks as cf

init_notebook_mode(connected = True) 
cf.go_offline 

df = pd.read_csv('imdb.csv')
df.rename(columns={'Runtime (Minutes)':'Runtime', 'Revenue (Millions)':'Revenue'}, inplace=True)

df.iplot()
```

I am using IDLE editor. The error I am getting is :-

```
AttributeError: module 'plotly.offline' has no attribute '__PLOTLY_OFFLINE_INITIALIZED'
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to why I might be getting this error and how to get rid of it.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @ChukUltima `df.iplot()`

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```